# BingMaps predefined pushpin icons

Tags: ajax, styles, bing-maps

I'm using the Ajax v.7 version of Bing Maps and want to change the pushpin icon.
I don't want to create new icons nor I want to draw on the canvas.
Is there a way to get some predefined puspins or to change the default one color.

the default one is: http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/7.0.20140904153057.64/i/poi_search.png

so i assume there must be others, but how to get them?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the icon you need to either use a URL to an image. Or hide the icon all together and use HTML instead (HTML 5 Canvas, SVG, and symbol fonts all work well). If you have a specific type of pushpin icon you want to create and/or function (i.e. be able to change color), let me know and I'll provide ore details.

Comment: I thought so :-(. Yes I am building some simle GIS application, and based on some property value I need to display an icon with different color. I tried the http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Canvas%20Pushpin%20Module but it does not work well and I had problems with it. So I'm still looking for a solution, apart of creating different icons for each color.

Comment: Try using htmlContent and in there have a span with a single character. And then use symbol fonts. This will allow you to easily change the size and color programmatically. I've done this in a few projects with success. Take a look at these fonts: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5Bclassifications%5D%5B0%5D=dingbat&filter%5Blicense%5D%5B0%5D=web